# Should (or shouldn't) the values in Flutter JSON files be quoted?

Tags: json, flutter

Let's first establish a detail. In the following code

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

void main() {
  var jsonStr = """{"count": 3}""";

  final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonStr);

  print(json['count']); // 3
}
```

the string to be parsed is `{"count": 3}` and not `{count: 3}` (with quotes around `count`).

Now suppose when
[persisting](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence)
by
[writing and then reading](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files),
we do not persist just the counter string on disk (as in the example at this last URL).
Suppose we persist in a JSON file instead.

When `writeJson()` below runs, it saves `{count: 3}` (and not `{"count": 3}`).
Hence it's no surprise that a subsequent loading in
`final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonString);`
fails—as we saw in the code above.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class CounterModel {
  int count = 0;

  ...

  factory CounterModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CounterModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CounterModelToJson(this);
}

class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.json');
  }

  Future<CounterModel> readJson() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      final jsonStr = await file.readAsString();
      final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonStr);
      final counter = CounterModel.fromJson(json);
      return counter;
    } catch (e) {
      return CounterModel(0);
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeJson(CounterModel counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    final stringToWrite = counter.toJson().toString();
    return file.writeAsString(stringToWrite);
  }
}
```

Should (or shouldn't) the values in Flutter JSON files be quoted?

#### Generated Code

For reference, the generated code follows.

```
CounterModel _$CounterModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CounterModel(
      json['count'] as int,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$CounterModelToJson(CounterModel instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'count': instance.count,
    };
```

Comment: No.  Why are you adding .toString? The output of .toJson() is a single string, ready for writing into the file.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Flutter JSON".  It's just normal JSON, and keys in JSON are strings, and strings are always quoted. https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I added the generated code for clarity.

Comment: @jamesdlin Understood. JSON is JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion arises from the fact the a typical Dart `toJson` method returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` - just as in your example. This isn't (yet) a string representation of JSON. However it is easily converted with:

```
final stringLookingLikeJson = json.encode(map); // {"foo":1}
```

Instead, if you `toString` the map, or call `print` which will implicitly toString it, you'll see Dart's default representation of a map contents e.g. `{foo:1}`. This is simply `Map`'s implementation of `toString` - note - not meant to look like JSON.

So, why doesn't a typical `toJson` return a string in JSON format? Why the need to use `json.encode()` to encode it? This is to allow nesting of more complex objects. A top level object's `toJson` might return a `Map<String, dynamic>` where some or all of the `dynamic`s are other maps and lists created by nested calls to `toJson`. Only at the end is `json.encode()` called on the top of that tree to convert it all, in one go, to a single JSON string.

So `toJson` is meant to return either a map (which will be encoded to a JSON object - inside `{}`) or a list (which will be encoded to a JSON array - inside `[]`) or even just a JSON primitive (string, number, bool). These can then be nested inside each other. The encoder does the conversion to JSON - adding the quotes, braces and brackets.

In conclusion you should change your code to:

```
  final stringToWrite = json.encode(counter.toJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you pointing to the printed in console, it should look like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  CounterModel modl = CounterModel(count: 3);

  print(modl.toJson());  // {count: 3}
  print("--------");
  print(jsonEncode(modl));  // {"count":3}
}

class CounterModel {
  int count;

  CounterModel({this.count = 0});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"count": count};
}
```

result:

[image]